# PhpStorm how to downgrade CLI Interpreter to bypass deprecated Function

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

I am trying to work on PhpStorm (version 2017.2.4) using older version of PHP files.

I realized that "mysql_.." gets strikethrough, and it says "Function mysql_.. is deprecated..".

I only have one PHP file that is affected by this issue.

[image]

I believe it happens because my PhpStorm (that I downloaded on my new PC) is running on PHP version 5.6.31 or (5.3 ?).

[image]

I am running PhpStorm on Windows machine, and has XAMPP Control Panel (v3.2.3) installed.

What would be the most fast way to bypass this?

On other site, it says "The MySQL extensionIs officially deprecated as of PHP 5.5 (released June 2013)."

Are they referring to version of CLI Interpreter or PHP language level?

I realized that using "mysqli_.." or "pdo_" would be an option, but I was not get it working and getting a lot of errors.
I found other Stackoverflow articles on these ("mysqli_.." or "pdo_"), but I am not sure whether this is the best solution for my situation.

Finally, I was trying to get the older version of CLI Interpreter and Googled for a long time, but I am not sure where to go.

Should I pursue using either "mysqli_.." or "pdo_" or try to downgrade CLI interpreter?

Comment: Avoid at all costs to use deprecated features. It is time to refactor your code ;)!

Comment: "Downgrading PHP Interpreter" will not help here. Either rewrite the code so it uses recommended `mysqli_*` or `pdo_*` ... or just disable that particular inspection in PhpStorm settings (HINT: use search and look for "deprecated" inspection for PHP). Keep in mind that if you wish to run your code on PHP 7.x you will have to rewrite those moments.

Comment: The issue with you seeing this warning despite the fact that your Language Level is set to 5.3 (where those functions are OK) is that PHP stubs are not really "version friendly" (same stub files used for any PHP version) when it comes to deprecated notices.

Comment: 1) *"Are they referring to version of CLI Interpreter or PHP language level?"* Language Level. You can use PHP 7.1 as interpreter but still specify 5.3 as language level -- it's for keywords/language functionality mainly .. stubs are not really that flexible here (as mentioned earlier). 2) *"I believe it happens because my PhpStorm is running on PHP version 5.6.31"* PhpStorm is NOT running on PHP.. as it's written in Java/Kotlin. Find a better wording for that part..

Comment: 3) *"I realized that using "mysqli_.." or "pdo_" would be an option, but I was not get it working and getting a lot of errors."* Then try again .. as it's the best option overall. No need to keep to already deprecated functionality at all (unless your code is something of limited usage (e.g. small site for personal needs etc)). There are many reasons why to make your code PHP 7.x compatible (so it can just run here -- no need to write in PHP 7.x only style) .. and performance and security are one of those.